# Can snmptranslate return the textual value of an integer defined in MIB?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I'm working with the IF-MIB and trying to get the text value of an integer using the tools available in net-snmp.

```
$ snmptranslate -Td IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus.1
IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus.1
ifAdminStatus OBJECT-TYPE
  -- FROM   IF-MIB
  SYNTAX    INTEGER {up(1), down(2), testing(3)} 
  MAX-ACCESS    read-write
  STATUS    current
  DESCRIPTION   "The desired state of the interface.  The testing(3) state
            indicates that no operational packets can be passed.  When a
            managed system initializes, all interfaces start with
            ifAdminStatus in the down(2) state.  As a result of either
            explicit management action or per configuration information
            retained by the managed system, ifAdminStatus is then
            changed to either the up(1) or testing(3) states (or remains
            in the down(2) state)."
::= { iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) mgmt(2) mib-2(1) interfaces(2) ifTable(2) ifEntry(1) ifAdminStatus(7) 1 }
```

The SYNTAX here shows that ifAdminStatus has three possible values, `up(1), down(2), testing(3)`. Is it possible to get the string representations (up, down testing) returned for given integer using the net-snmp tools like snmptranslate somehow?